# How to use one selenium webdriver for multiple browsing tabs in one window and access them individually?

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

Based on what I've read in stackoverflow, it seems that I need to send keys to open tab and then open a particular website. However, it's quite complicated to do so and I ended up using multiple webdrivers because it's way simpler.

Here's my dummy code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=dirPath + "/chromedriver" + str(1),
            options = chrome_options
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=dirPath + "/chromedriver" + str(2),
            options = chrome_options
driver1.get("website1")
driver2.get("website2")
```

This then can be parallelized using multiprocessing. However it seems that this consumes a lot of RAM especially if I parallelize 10 webdrivers, each for one window. I was thinking of opening 10 tabs in 1 browser and then access each tab separately but got no solution. The goal is to open multiple tabs in one browser and use something like driver.get() in that tab without using keys.

Additional info: this setup crashed with seg fault 11 on pycharm but works fine in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in method for Selenium to open a new tab. However you can pass a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab

```
driver.find_element_by_css_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "T")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) # This will switch the Selenium control to the current tab
```

But even this probably won't work in Chrome. I recommend you use some GUI automation tool like pyautogui to do it:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 't') # This will open a new tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

You can try both.

Comment: can I send keys 4 times and then assign each tab to a variable to then be used with get

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I think it'll work. But you can't perform actions on multiple tabs in the same window simultaneously